# Advice on graphics card

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I'm looking to upgrade my computers graphics from integrated graphics to a dedicated graphics card. My question is two fold:

1. Is this the PCI Express slot?[image]
2. With an AMD A10-7800 Radeon R7, 12 Compute Cores 4C and 8GB RAM, what would you recommend as an ideal graphics card to run let's say Civ 6 on high settings?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hardware Recs! Question 1, falls under technical support requests, which our affiliate site [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) may be better equipped to handle. I would highly advise editing out Question 1 and expanding on Question 2 to minimize chance of closure. Question 2 is on topic for our site, but in it's current form is a bit too broad to give you a solid recommendation. It would help if you listed more criteria such as price, target fps, etc.

Answer (score 2):

this is indeed a PCIe slot (x16).

The built-in GPU could possibly make it for low/medium settings but if you want high / play to other games, I would recommand a little card like a 1050Ti (roughly 170€ / 160£ / 170$).

However, you have to know that this CPU is not the best for gaming and could limit with games relying a lot on CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Rx 560 and Gtx 1050Ti are way to go according to your needs but your processor doesn't seem to get full use of these graphics card if possible upgrade to minimum ryzen 3 or intel i3 otherwise you can get 40+ fps on high settings with your amd apu buy any of them which is cheaper in your country and you can see benchmarks on YouTube with your apu paired with these two Gpus.